# Create a new worksheet based on range if existing one cannot be found

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a new worksheet, by copying the 'Template', if one does not exist.

The names of the sheets are based on Column A (list starting from A5 of the 'Master'). The list in 'Master' will be updated daily.

I check the list for new names by looping through the existing Sheets. If a cell in Column A (Sheet 'Master') already has a worksheet with the name, then do nothing and go to the next cell. If a name in the list is not among the sheetnames of the Workbook, a worksheet would be added (a copy of the 'Template') and named after the cell value.

I am able to create the new worksheets but for every existing worksheet, the macro creates additional worksheets ('template(2)', 'template(3)', 'template(4)', and so on).

What should I do to eliminate those new sheets of 'template(#)'?

Here is my code:

```
Sub AutoAddSheet()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("A5")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange

    On Error Resume Next

    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        .Name = MyCell.Value
        .Cells(2, 1) = MyCell.Value

    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    MyCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=MyCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & MyCell.Value & "'!A1"

Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: You realize you picked the answer that does 2 loops over an answer that loops once and uses the MATCH function, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the sheet exists first, here's an efficient function I wrote to do so:

```
Function CheckSheetExists(ByVal name As String)

' checks if a worksheet already exists

Dim retVal As Boolean

retVal = False

For s = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(s).name = name Then
        retVal = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next s

CheckSheetExists = retVal

End Function
```

So, amend your code to this:

```
If CheckSheetExists(MyCell.Value) = false then

    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        .Name = MyCell.Value
        .Cells(2, 1) = MyCell.Value

    End With
End If
```

Comment: That's awesome - thank you so much and Happy New Year!

Comment: No problem, please use the tick box to accept my answer if you're happy with it to assist other SO users. Happy New Year to you too :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try it in a different way. First, loop through all `Worksheets` in the workbook and save their names in `sheetNames` array.

Then, for each cell in your range, you can use the `Match` function to see if it already exists in your workbook. If the `Match` fails, it means this `MyCell.Value` is not found in the worksheets names >> so create it.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoAddSheet()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
Dim sheetNames() As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("A5", Sheets("Master").Range("A5").End(xlDown))

' put all sheet name from Range A5 in "Master" sheet into an array

ReDim sheetNames(1 To 100) ' = Application.Transpose(MyRange.Value)

i = 1
' loop through all worksheets and get their names
For Each ws In Worksheets
    sheetNames(i) = ws.Name

    i = i + 1
Next ws

'resice array to actual number of sheets in workbook
ReDim Preserve sheetNames(1 To i - 1)

For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells

    ' sheet name not found in workbook sheets array >> create it
    If IsError(Application.Match(MyCell.Value, sheetNames, 0)) Then
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            .Name = MyCell.Value
            .Cells(2, 1) = MyCell.Value
        End With

        MyCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=MyCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & MyCell.Value & "'!A1"

    Else '<-- sheet name exists in array (don't create a new one)
        ' do nothing
    End If
Next MyCell

' ====== Delete the worksheets with (#) section =====
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In Worksheets       
    If ws.Name Like "*(?)*" Then ws.Delete
Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me that `IsError(Application.Match(x,y,0))` works while `IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(x,y,0))` doesn't!

Comment: Once you learn how to use the `Application.Match` you won't stop using it !

Comment: I actually [answered a question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41433911/6535336) yesterday where I originally hoped to use `WorksheetFunction.Match`, but couldn't overcome the problem that an unmatched value generates a run-time error before reaching the `IsError`.  I gave up and posted a solution using a `Select Case` instead.  (Which is probably a better method for the particular scenario, but was further away from the OP's code.)  If I had realised that `Application.Match` worked differently, I may have answered differently.

Answer (score 0):

I just tweaked your code a little to make sure all references were fully qualified. It should be easier to follow and you don't run the risk of Excel getting confused about where to copy from/to.

*Tested and works for me*

```
Sub AutoAddSheet()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("A5")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

Dim wksTemplate As Worksheet
Set wksTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    wksTemplate.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

    With wsNew
        .Name = MyCell.Value
        .Cells(2, 1) = MyCell.Value
    End With

    MyCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=MyCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & MyCell.Value & "'!A1"
Next MyCell

End Sub
```